# Can't create instance since no default constructor, but only available constructor is not public. How to call public members from class?

Tags: c#, .net, api, trading

I am trying to access information from a API trading position by going

```
Position position = new Position();
int positionQuantity = position.Net;
Console.WriteLine("position amount is: " + positionQuantity);
```

However, it is giving me a red line under
    new Position();

and saying the T4.API.Position has no default constructors defined.

but then if I go

```
Position position = default(Position); 
int positionQuantity = position.Net;
Console.WriteLine("position amount is: " + positionQuantity);
```

"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

So it is wanting me to use the "new" keyword but I can't because it says it does not have a default constructor

I opened up their Position class and it does have a bunch of delegates should I use one of those?

there is no default constructor however, they do have a constructor with 3 arguments, however, it is an "internal"

```
public class Position
{
    public delegate DelegateName(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    // a bunch of other delegates

    internal Position(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        //properties, etc..
    }

    public int Net
    {
        get { return _net; }
    }
}
```

Not sure how to call the member Net if I can't create an instance because no default constructor and the only available constructor is not public but internal?

Comment: The question as asked can't be answered on SO - have you tried to ask "them" (assuming you are talking about library authors) about proper way to use that class and why there is no default constructor.

Comment: If the constructor is internal you it maens that you should not create an instance of this class directly. It's probably a class designed for internal use. Read the documentation or ask the authors of this library what you can do with this class.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some reasons why a class will not have an available default constructor:

- The only constructor(s) the class have requires parameters
- The default constructor is private, like in singleton
- The class is static, and can't be instansiated, like System.IO.File
- The class is abstract and is  designed as a base class for the classes you should use, like System.Drawing.Image

I've probably forgot to list some reasons, but I hope you get the picture: You have the code so you can see for yourself, we don't...

Answer (score 0):

As **MSDN** says

> **If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default
>   instance constructor is automatically provided**. ***That default
>   constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct
>   base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible
>   parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.*** If
>   the class is abstract then the declared accessibility for the default
>   constructor is protected. Otherwise, the declared accessibility for
>   the default constructor is public.

Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are 
given a public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to 
enable class instantiation.

*In your case you must post your queries to the API vendors as we can not see the code and they are the best doctors for the issue*.